# JS Injection in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I just upgraded to WP 4.3.1 on one of my websites. After upgrade (which seemed to go with no problems at all), I noticed that the layout of my pages has changed. There is a bar across the top of my page (not the admin bar) that wasn't there before. When I inspect the element there, I see a whole bunch of new code that is not being created by any of my plugins. And I cannot find the source of this injection in any of the provided php files. I have no idea where it is coming from, but I suspect that something in the WP 4.3.1 package has been compromised, or maybe there is a callout to a site somewhere that injects this code.

Anyway, this is a BIG problem and I don't know how to fix it.

I've copied the injected injected code below. It appears in all the pages on my site, right below the  tag. Interestingly it can only be seen by "inspecting element" in the browser; page source does not reveal it (I've added some line breaks to make it more readable, but this is exactly what shows up in my page.

This same problem occurs on every site where I upgrade to WP 4.3.1. I hope someone can fix this problem IMMEDIATELY!!

Clearing cache, history & cookies doesn't resolve the problem. I can't tell where this injected code is coming from. Also, Google doesn't seem to be much help in telling me anything useful about http://kfc.i.illuminationes.com/snitch, which is one of the links that is being created.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/js-injection-after-wp

Comment: Posted this question there too, but didnt go the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Our site was infected, this is what we did to get rid of it
Thanks to [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/js-injection-kfciilluminationescomsnitch) discussion which led me to a more [detailed one](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/js-injection-after-wp/page/2?replies=43)

1. Connect via ssh to the server
2. Check the directory structure and find out recently created / modified directories
3. Check recently modified files for `<script>`. I found many files having JavaScript inserted which would connect to external sites.
4. As these calls were made on each page, I checked header.php in wp-content/themes/your-theme directory. (check the ones you are not using as well as that might be infected but may not show in radar)
5. You might also want to check footer.php for infection.
6. Re check file permissions on server as per WordPress Hardening guidelines on Codex
7. Delete unrequired ftp accounts in FileZilla (or its equivalent)

If you use any caching, delete entire cache.
You can verify if this worked using devtools network tab.